# Converting column values from factors into column names and assigning them values

Tags: r

I want to convert columns that are factors, then assign those factors as an independent column, and when that value appeared in the column as a factor, assign it a value of 1 and all elsewhere 0, and repeat this for any columns that are factors.

Although, how  to do this with a function, such that I can use it within a `data.frame`.

For example, given this dataset:

```
   wgt hgt age    id    sex
 1:  64  57   8 black female
 2:  71  59  10 black female
 3:  53  49   6 black female
 4:  67  62  11 black female
 5:  55  51   8 white female
 6:  58  50   7 white female
 7:  77  55  10 white   male
 8:  57  48   9 white   male
 9:  56  42  10 brown   male
10:  51  42   6 brown   male
11:  76  61  12 brown   male
12:  68  57   9 brown   male
```

I want the output so that:

```
   wgt hgt age  black white brown female male
 1:  64  57   8   1    0       0   1      0
 2:  71  59  10   1    0       0   1      0
 3:  53  49   6   1    0       0   1      0
 4:  67  62  11   1    0       0   1      0
 5:  55  51   8   0    1       0   1      0
 6:  58  50   7   0    1       0   1      0
 7:  77  55  10   0    1       0   0      1
 8:  57  48   9   0    1       0   0      1
 9:  56  42  10   0    0       1   0      1
10:  51  42   6   0    0       1   0      1
11:  76  61  12   0    0       1   0      1
12:  68  57   9   0    0       1   0      1
```

So that if I run a `data.frame` likeso:

```
data.frame(test.weight, function(x..))
```

Given that test.weight is of the same rows as the dataframe that assigns the factors into columns. Could this be done in a general format, so that it always picks those columns that are `factors` and performs the following output as above?

reproducible code:

```
structure(list(wgt = c(64L, 71L, 53L, 67L, 55L, 58L, 77L, 57L, 
56L, 51L, 76L, 68L), hgt = c(57L, 59L, 49L, 62L, 51L, 50L, 55L, 
48L, 42L, 42L, 61L, 57L), age = c(8L, 10L, 6L, 11L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 
9L, 10L, 6L, 12L, 9L), id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("black", "brown", "white"
), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("female", "male"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `model.matrix` in `base R`

```
nm1 <- names(which(dt1[, unlist(lapply(.SD, is.factor))]))
dt2 <- dt1[, lapply(.SD, function(x) model.matrix(~ x - 1)), .SDcols = nm1]
setnames(dt2, sub(".*x", "", names(dt2)))
cbind(dt1, dt2)
```

-output

```
    wgt hgt age    id    sex black brown white female male
 1:  64  57   8 black female     1     0     0      1    0
 2:  71  59  10 black female     1     0     0      1    0
 3:  53  49   6 black female     1     0     0      1    0
 4:  67  62  11 black female     1     0     0      1    0
 5:  55  51   8 white female     0     0     1      1    0
 6:  58  50   7 white female     0     0     1      1    0
 7:  77  55  10 white   male     0     0     1      0    1
 8:  57  48   9 white   male     0     0     1      0    1
 9:  56  42  10 brown   male     0     1     0      0    1
10:  51  42   6 brown   male     0     1     0      0    1
11:  76  61  12 brown   male     0     1     0      0    1
12:  68  57   9 brown   male     0     1     0      0    1
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
dt1 %>% 
   select(where(negate(is.numeric))) %>% 
   map_dfc(~ model.matrix(~ .x -1) %>% 
         as_tibble) %>% 
   rename_all(~ str_remove(., "\\.x")) %>%
   bind_cols(dt1, .)
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep this within a function, such that I won't have to specifically select the columns. It can find them on a condition, like the column being a factor?

Comment: @jj_ellison from the `dput`, `sex` is a `character` class

Comment: I do apologise, that was my mistake. I have corrected it, should have been factor.

Comment: @jj_ellison its okay..  I added another solution with `tidyverse`, where it selects the column if it is not numeric

Comment: That works brilliantly! Although, I've been using it as a function. However, is there a way to set it to `FALSE` when no factors are available in the data. So, when I use it as a function, I won't get an error such that `variable x is missing`, because its been set to `FALSE`?

Comment: @jj_ellison you can use `if/else` condition i.e. `if(length(nm1) > 0) {... do this ...}`

Comment: I've got it to work, thanks! I've noticed that swapping `bind_cols()` for `bind_rows()` helps re-introduce the data given the last condition you presented.

Comment: @jj_ellison In this example, you are appending the orginal data with the new data columns created within `map_dfc`. If you use `bind_rows`, that would be a different task

Comment: @You're right, it doesn't seem to be the most effective. For example, If I want to test between it has factors or it doesn't have factors. I thought of appending an `else if ( ...)`, however, my approach had `bind_rows()`, in one `if-statement`, and `bind_cols()` in the other. However, It doesn't work effectively, because it always goes for the first if statement. Is there a better alternative to this?

Comment: @jj_ellison In the first code block, 'nm1' is the names of the factor column names.  If there are none, it returns `character(0)` i..e `names(which(sapply(mtcars, is.factor)))#
character(0)` and the `if` condition is checking if the length is 0 or greater than 0.  If no factor, it is 0 .  So,we are only doing the `if` condition with `length > 0` i.e. when there are at least one factor.

Comment: @jj_ellison Can you post as a new question as your code blocks are not very clear to me

Comment: I've uploaded it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66665437/giving-a-conditional-onto-a-function-that-performs-for-factors

Comment: @jj_ellison I think the issue is because the location of invoking the `if` condition.  Please check the solution I posted there

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to apply hot-encoding with library `fastDummies`,
By applying this technique it is possible to convert categorical columns to binary columns (0,1).

```
library(fastDummies)

output_df <-fastDummies::dummy_cols(df,  
                                    select_columns = c('id', 'sex'))
```

Console output:

```
#    wgt hgt age    id    sex id_black id_brown id_white sex_female sex_male
# 1:  64  57   8 black female        1        0        0          1        0
# 2:  71  59  10 black female        1        0        0          1        0
# 3:  53  49   6 black female        1        0        0          1        0
# 4:  67  62  11 black female        1        0        0          1        0
# 5:  55  51   8 white female        0        0        1          1        0
# 6:  58  50   7 white female        0        0        1          1        0
# 7:  77  55  10 white   male        0        0        1          0        1
# 8:  57  48   9 white   male        0        0        1          0        1
# 9:  56  42  10 brown   male        0        1        0          0        1
#10:  51  42   6 brown   male        0        1        0          0        1
#11:  76  61  12 brown   male        0        1        0          0        1
#12:  68  57   9 brown   male        0        1        0          0        1
```

### data

```
df <-structure(list(wgt = c(64L, 71L, 53L, 67L, 55L, 58L, 77L, 57L, 
56L, 51L, 76L, 68L), hgt = c(57L, 59L, 49L, 62L, 51L, 50L, 55L, 
48L, 42L, 42L, 61L, 57L), age = c(8L, 10L, 6L, 11L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 
9L, 10L, 6L, 12L, 9L), id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("black", "brown", "white"
), class = "factor"), sex = c("female", "female", "female", "female", 
"female", "female", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male"
)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))
```