# Giving a conditional onto a function that performs for factors

Tags: r, function

This questions ties onto this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66664944/converting-column-values-from-factors-into-column-names-and-assigning-them-value), and at @Akruns request I'm asking for something similar.

Essentially, If I insert a dataframe within the following conditional:

```
if(length(weight) > 0) {weight %>% 
    select(where(negate(is.numeric))) %>% 
    map_dfc(~ model.matrix(~ .x -1) %>% 
              as_tibble) %>% 
    rename_all(~ str_remove(., "\\.x")) %>%
    bind_rows(weight, .)  
}
```

Assignment:

```
#Following @Akruns mention for turning numeric into factor:
i1 <- sapply(weight, is.numeric); df[i1] <- lapply(weight[i1], factor) and then use the Filter(function(x) is.factor(x)|is.character(x), weight)

test = function(data) {
  x = as.data.frame(Reduce(cbind, lapply(x, function(col) model.matrix(~ . -1, data = data.frame(col)))))
  setNames(x, sub(pattern = "^col", replacement = "", names(x)))
  
}
  
test(weight)
#Missing column names                     
1  64 57  8 1 0 0 1 0
2  71 59 10 1 0 0 1 0
3  53 49  6 1 0 0 1 0
4  67 62 11 1 0 0 1 0
5  55 51  8 0 0 1 1 0
6  58 50  7 0 0 1 1 0
7  77 55 10 0 0 1 0 1
8  57 48  9 0 0 1 0 1
9  56 42 10 0 1 0 0 1
10 51 42  6 0 1 0 0 1
11 76 61 12 0 1 0 0 1
12 68 57  9 0 1 0 0 1
```

Then if `weight` has factors, it will split columns that are factors into columns and assign them values with `1` where it appeared before and `0` elsewhere.

However, if I input a `numeric` only dataframe, it returns `character(0)`. The question is, how to give the following function a conditional such that whether the dataframe for example `x` is numeric then return the dataframe as it is. If it is a factor, then return the requested output.

The reason I request this is because I'm looking to implement this within another function, that will include many dataframe where some have only numeric and others include factors. In that case, I can denote the dataframe as `x` within the function.

My edit of the function:

```
fact_col <- function(x){
if(length(x) > 0) {
  weight_sub <- x %>% 
    select(where(is.factor)) 
  weight_sub %>%
    map_dfc(~ model.matrix(~ .x -1) %>% 
              as_tibble) %>% 
    rename_all(~ str_remove(., "\\.x")) %>%
    bind_cols(weight_sub, .) -> x
 x<- x%>% select(!where(is.factor))
 x<- data.frame(sapply(x, as.numeric))
}}
```

expected output:

```
#when x is numeric
function(x) { ... }
 Richness pat
1        20   1
2        17   2
3        18   3
4        19   4
5        11   5
6        15   6
7        17   7
8        15   8
9        15   9
10        9  10
11       13  11
12       14  12

#when x is a factor
function(x) { ... }

 wgt hgt age    id    sex black brown white female male
1   64  57   8 black female     1     0     0      1    0
2   71  59  10 black female     1     0     0      1    0
3   53  49   6 black female     1     0     0      1    0
4   67  62  11 black female     1     0     0      1    0
5   55  51   8 white female     0     0     1      1    0
6   58  50   7 white female     0     0     1      1    0
7   77  55  10 white   male     0     0     1      0    1
8   57  48   9 white   male     0     0     1      0    1
9   56  42  10 brown   male     0     1     0      0    1
10  51  42   6 brown   male     0     1     0      0    1
11  76  61  12 brown   male     0     1     0      0    1
12  68  57   9 brown   male     0     1     0      0    1
```

reproducible code:

```
structure(list(wgt = c(64L, 71L, 53L, 67L, 55L, 58L, 77L, 57L, 
56L, 51L, 76L, 68L), hgt = c(57L, 59L, 49L, 62L, 51L, 50L, 55L, 
48L, 42L, 42L, 61L, 57L), age = c(8L, 10L, 6L, 11L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 
9L, 10L, 6L, 12L, 9L), id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("black", "brown", "white"
), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("female", "male"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to split the code before we use the `if` i.e. `select` the columns that are `factor` and create a new object ('weight_sub'), then check the `length` on the 'weight_sub', `if` it is greater than 0, do the rest of `model.matrix` and assign it back to 'weight'

```
weight_sub <- weight %>% 
 select(where(is.factor)) 
 
if(length(weight_sub) > 0) {
  weight_sub %>%
   map_dfc(~ model.matrix(~ .x -1) %>% 
             as_tibble) %>% 
     rename_all(~ str_remove(., "\\.x")) %>%
      bind_cols(weight, .) -> weight

  }
```

-output

```
#   wgt hgt age    id    sex black brown white female male
#1   64  57   8 black female     1     0     0      1    0
#2   71  59  10 black female     1     0     0      1    0
#3   53  49   6 black female     1     0     0      1    0
#4   67  62  11 black female     1     0     0      1    0
#5   55  51   8 white female     0     0     1      1    0
#6   58  50   7 white female     0     0     1      1    0
#7   77  55  10 white   male     0     0     1      0    1
#8   57  48   9 white   male     0     0     1      0    1
#9   56  42  10 brown   male     0     1     0      0    1
#10  51  42   6 brown   male     0     1     0      0    1
#11  76  61  12 brown   male     0     1     0      0    1
#12  68  57   9 brown   male     0     1     0      0    1
```

As a negative test, do this by checking if it is a `character` class column

```
weight_sub <- weight %>% 
 select(where(is.character)) 
 
if(length(weight_sub) > 0) {
  weight_sub %>%
   map_dfc(~ model.matrix(~ .x -1) %>% 
             as_tibble) %>% 
     rename_all(~ str_remove(., "\\.x")) %>%
      bind_cols(weight, .) -> weight

  }
```

No output as the `if` condition returns `FALSE`, thus the 'weight' dataset remains the same without adding any new columns

---

In the update, if the OP is also using `numeric` columns to be passed into `model.matrix`, it just returns the same column i.e. one column (as we are looping over columns with `map`) with the column name as `.x` (from `model.matrix` formula).  This `.x` column name is removed with `rename_all` when we use `str_remove`, leaving a blank column name, which by default is filled with a column name assigned as 'col' from `_dfc`.  To prevent, that, we can use an `if/else` condition before doing this to append the original column name as suffix for those having one column output and is a numeric one

```
weight %>%
    imap_dfc(~ {
        nm1 <- .y
        tmp <- model.matrix(~ .x - 1) %>%
           as_tibble
       if(ncol(tmp) == 1 && class(tmp[[1]]) == 'numeric') {
          names(tmp) <- paste0(names(tmp), nm1)
       }
      tmp
     }) %>% 
      rename_all(~ str_remove(., "\\.x"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 8
#     wgt   hgt   age black brown white female  male
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    64    57     8     1     0     0      1     0
# 2    71    59    10     1     0     0      1     0
# 3    53    49     6     1     0     0      1     0
# 4    67    62    11     1     0     0      1     0
# 5    55    51     8     0     0     1      1     0
# 6    58    50     7     0     0     1      1     0
# 7    77    55    10     0     0     1      0     1
# 8    57    48     9     0     0     1      0     1
# 9    56    42    10     0     1     0      0     1
#10    51    42     6     0     1     0      0     1
#11    76    61    12     0     1     0      0     1
#12    68    57     9     0     1     0      0     1
```

---

Or we do this with `Map` in `base R`

```
 out <- do.call(cbind, unname(Map(function(x, y) {
      tmp <- as.data.frame(model.matrix(~x -1))
      if(ncol(tmp) == 1 & class(tmp[[1]]) == 'numeric') {
          names(tmp) <- paste0(names(tmp), y)}
          tmp
          }, weight, names(weight))))
names(out) <- sub('^x', '', names(out))
out
#   wgt hgt age black brown white female male
#1   64  57   8     1     0     0      1    0
#2   71  59  10     1     0     0      1    0
#3   53  49   6     1     0     0      1    0
#4   67  62  11     1     0     0      1    0
#5   55  51   8     0     0     1      1    0
#6   58  50   7     0     0     1      1    0
#7   77  55  10     0     0     1      0    1
#8   57  48   9     0     0     1      0    1
#9   56  42  10     0     1     0      0    1
#10  51  42   6     0     1     0      0    1
#11  76  61  12     0     1     0      0    1
#12  68  57   9     0     1     0      0    1
```

Comment: I have included how it's represented as a function in the main text. However, the function does not return an output. Perhaps, I've arranged it incorrectly, please have a look! I would really appreciate it. Furthermore, is it possible to give a conditional with `select(where(is.character))` such that, if the data has both `factor` and `character` then split it, if it has neither, do not split it, return a character vector like: `This has no factors nor characters`, and leave the initial dataframe as is?

Comment: @jj_ellison you can change to `select(where(~ is.character(.)|is.factor(.)))` to make use of both

Comment: @jj_ellison the `if(length(x) > 0) {` should be after the 'weight_sub` i.e it would run on the `if(length(weight_sub) > 0)`

Comment: ```select(where(~ is.character(.)|is.factor(.)))``` this is helpful! Although, I tried to rework your code using base `R` only, to include all types of strings when available using: ```function(data) {
  x = Filter(function(x) is.numeric(x)|is.factor(x)|is.character(x), data)
  x = as.data.frame(Reduce(cbind, lapply(x, function(col) model.matrix(~ . -1, data = data.frame(col)))))
  setNames(x, sub(pattern = "^col", replacement = "", names(x)))
}``` The columns that are numeric lose their names because they're renamed `col`, is there a way to fix this by giving them the original names?

Comment: @jj_ellison I have a doubt with numeric columns.  How do you want to convert the numeric to 1, 0.  is it all values > 0 as 1 and others 0?

Comment: @jj_ellison Perhaps an option is to first convert the `numeric` columns to `factor` and then do the `select` i.e. `weight %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), factor)) %>% select(where(~ is.factor(.)|is.character(.)))`

Comment: Surprisingly the numerical columns do not change string values, they remain numeric, whilst the rest of the code works for factors or characters. The only problem is that the numeric columns are renamed `col`, whilst those changed are given `col_` where the underspace represents their values as factors. My question is how to have the numerical columns retain their original column names when the second `x` function is performed? I'm trying to keep this strinctly base R so its subsettable and easily transferable. Though I agree that tidyverse makes this more efficient

Comment: @jj_ellison can you try the method that I mentioned above ie to convert to factor.  In `base R` it would be `i1 <- sapply(weight, is.numeric); df[i1] <- lapply(df[i1], factor)` and then use the `Filter(function(x) is.factor(x)|is.character(x), df1)`  I would create a copy of the dataset before you do the conversion in case you want to keep the original type later

Comment: After trying the code you mentioned previously, I've noticed that it splits each value that was numeric, transformed into factor, into individual columns, and where it appeared its assigned the value 1 and elsewhere zero. Because these values are unique, each column is assigned only once a value 1. This interpretation would come in handy when trying to deal with presence and absence data. Thank you for the technique! Though, I still question how to convert the original names of numerical values in the assignment I provided before.

Comment: @jj_ellison can you update your post with an example and expected output so that it is clear.  The `factor` conversion does create new columns.  I am not sure how you would want that output

Comment: @jj_ellison I understand the issue.  Try `weight %>% imap_dfc(~ {nm1 <- .y; tmp <- model.matrix(~ .x - 1) %>% as_tibble; if(ncol(tmp) == 1 && class(tmp[[1]]) == 'numeric') names(tmp) <- paste0(names(tmp), nm1); tmp}) %>% rename_all(~ str_remove(., "\\.x"))`  Here, we are loopping over all the columns.  The reason is that in numeric, the column name is `.x` only and it gets lost after the rename_at step

Comment: @jj_ellison I think the code block in my comment just before you cmmented should fix that issue

Comment: It works, though what's the base R equivalent? I notice that `function(col)` seems to append its values on numeric values, whilst removing their columnn names?

Comment: @jj_ellison updated the post with `base R`

Comment: Thanks for the output! works brilliantly. I've managed to fix the missing column name issue with my previous code. I think I found your precise and logical nature towards code rather intimidating, so became very dependent on your craft: ```function(data) {
  x = Filter(function(x) is.numeric(x)|is.factor(x)|is.character(x), data)
  x = as.data.frame(Reduce(cbind, lapply(x, function(col) model.matrix(~ . -1, data = data.frame(col)))))
  names(x)[1:ncol(Filter(is.numeric, weight))] <- names(Filter(is.numeric, data))
  setNames(x, sub(pattern = "^col", replacement = "", names(x)))
  
}```